# Read a text file, store it, and sort this data in ascending order

Tags: c++, file, sorting

As you could understand from the title, I'm really a novice in this programming environment.
I'd like to ask you for help: I need to read a file like:

```
11:02,11:06
15:45,16:05
...
```

These data are one above the other one. So we have 11 columns (11 characters plus newline) and 239 rows.
In the original file they are all sorted randomly. I should sort them in ascending order.
At the end, it would be nice of course to visualize the output.
So far, I have done the first step, I'm reading the file "char by char". But I can't proceed further; my knowledge doesn't permit me that. I would be really glad if someone could help me. I really need this stuff.

Comment: What is 'crescent order'?

Comment: Just approach it step by step - firstly read csv line by line https://www.google.com.au/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=read+csv+line+by+line+c%2B%2B&oq=read+csv+line+by+line+c%2B%2B&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30.284.5223.0.5471.25.15.0.10.10.0.245.2936.0j12j3.15.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.Tj-9OGnIXVc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.aGc&fp=5741f610caf3269&biw=952&bih=999 and store it in a vector. Sorting is covered very well in whatever tutorial you find, so shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am really sorry, I meant ascending order.
Is a txt file, does it change something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't really help with "Here's a very vague description of my needs. I can't really explain it, and I have no code to show what I'm trying to do. Can you help me?" questions. We can only help with specific questions about things that might help others in the future; we can't assist with individual projects or assignments based on a list of requirements, I'm afraid. The [faq] and [about] pages can help you with the types of questions we can help answer. I'm afraid I have to vote to close this as not a real question. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but I think question is clear, I'd like to read, store and then sort a file. In ascending order.

Comment: I tried a bit by myself, but I don't know how to proceed. For example, once the data is ridden with a class called "readfile", how can i store it in another class called "storefile"? and then how to take the array just created and then sort it in ascending order with another class called "sortfile"?

Comment: I am just asking some help! what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data generator script in Perl; it generates 2 times on each line, and the second is always later than the first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $i (1..239)
{
    my $h1 = 10 + rand 8;
    my $h2 = $h1 + 1;
    my $m1 = rand 60;
    my $m2 = rand 60;
    printf "%.2d:%.2d,%.2d:%.2d\n", $h1, $m1, $h2, $m2;
}
```

And here's a modestly verbose C++ program that sorts the Perl-generated data file the same way that the Unix `sort` program does.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> input;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        input.push_back(line);

    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end());

    //C++03
    //for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
    //    std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    //C++11
    for (auto &it : input)
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

There might be ways to compress the C++, but it works for me (G++ 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.3):

```
    g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra rs.cpp -o rs
```

There are definitely ways to compress the Perl code.